# How to draw/keep a line on top of a PictureBox?

Tags: c#, line, picturebox

I have an line that cross to PictureBox, When I refresh the pictureBox the line that crosses goes to the back. To put the line in front again I set pictureBox to the background after refreshing the image. But I'm using an Webcam and grabbing frames and showing to the pictureBoX and this causes that the line that stay in front of pictureBox flickers in the zone of the pictureBox.

Any Suggestion to solve this without making an Buffered line and adding to the image?

The code that I'm using is:

```
System.Drawing.Pen myPen;
myPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 0, 0, 200, 200);
myPen.Dispose();
formGraphics.Dispose();
```

And in an method that is scheduled by:

```
Application.Idle += ProcessFrame():
```

An the processFrame is:

```
private void ProcessFrame()
{

Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageFrame = capture.QueryFrame();

//after some image processing

pictureBox.Image = ImageFrame;
// after this the line goes to the background and I need to send the picturebox
   //Background to show the line in front of poctureBox
pictureBox.SendToBack();

}
```

this causes the line to flicker in the place where the pictureBox is placed, because the method pictureBox.SendToBack() is called after the image update.

I can do a backbuffer and generate the line that crosses the pictureBox together with the image I'm displaying, but the line is longer that the pictureBox.

Any other way to do this without backbuffer?

Thanks

Comment: How are you drawing the line?

Comment: I'm using an pen and drawing using drawline

Comment: Please post the code you are using to draw and in which method this code is run.

Comment: Code included on original post.

Comment: @HSO - there is no need to delete your answer, if it solved your problem then it is an acceptable answer.  Unfortunately we have some users here who click faster than they read.

Comment: @joce - please don't criticize or downvote a poster when they resolve their own question **by posting the solution they found** - that's not helpful, and additionally means that questions hang around forever with no resolution.